# Laravel Postgres SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near “”“”

Tags: laravel, postgresql, datatable, yajra-datatable

to display the data is fine, but when doing a search an error will occur.
I do not know what happened.

**Controller :**

```
public function data()
{
    if(request()->ajax()) {
        return datatables()
        ->of(DB::table('data_pmks')->select('id_pmks','tgl_pelaksanaan', 'nama', 'jenis_kelamin','jenis_pmks','jenis_pelayanan','jenis_intervensi')
        ->orderBy('id_pmks', 'desc')
        ->where('is_active','1')->where('jenis_intervensi',Session::get('intervensi')))
        ->editColumn('mybutton', static function ($row) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success detail" href="/opd/pmks/data/edit/'.$row->id_pmks.'">Detail</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger detail" href="/opd/pmks/data/hapus/'.$row->id_pmks.'">Hapus</a>';
        })->editColumn('myIndex', function ($row) {
            return (int)$row->id_pmks;
        })->editColumn('select_orders', static function ($row) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" name="cheking[]" value="'.$row->id_pmks.'"/>';
        })
        ->rawColumns(['select_orders','myIndex','mybutton'])
        ->make(true);
        }
    return  view('opd.pmks.data_pmks');
}
```

**error message :**

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

it just adds `searchable: false` to the column settings in javascript.